# How to read csv on a remote server with ssis

Tags: csv, ssis, connection

I would like to know the easiest way to read a csv file located on a shared folder on a remote server.

I'm doing this only for testing reasons, I don't really need to accomplish anything more than this task.

The scenario is:

- I have a virtual machine A (which is on an azure virtual network) that hosts a csv file.
- On another virtual machine B (which is on another azure virtual network) I'm running my package.

I would like this package to read the file from A and write it on a cloud sql server. The package is currently running on B.

I am stuck at the very beginning.
I was just trying to create a flat file connection. When I use a UNC path as the name of the file it just doesn't work. It allows me to set the file format parameters but the error I get is "Columns are not defined for this connection manager" and I am not able to go on.

Can anyone explain how to achieve the task, what am I not considering ? 
I apologise if this is a dummy question, I am new to SSIS and networking in general.

Thank you all in advance.